# JS Declare and assign multi variable inLine es6?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, declaration, destructuring

it possible to declare and assign multi variable in same line with es6 syntax ?
just example here, 
suppose i need to give value "50" to `mX,mY,mXDZ,mYDZ`.
How i can perform this ?

```
let [mX,mY,mXDZ,mYDZ] = 50;
let mX,mY,mXDZ,mYDZ = 50; // !just why not!
```

I am mainly looking for readability.

Comment: Is it 50 or 500?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not exactly possible. Destructuring needs a thing with multiple values<sup>1</sup> to be assigned to multiple targets, not a single value. You can however cheat:

```
function* repeat(x) { while(true) yield x; }

let [mX, mY, mXDZ, mYDZ] = repeat(50);
```

Apart from that, in a multiple declaration every variable needs its own initialiser:

```
let mX = 50, mY = 50, mXDZ = 50, mYDZ = 50;
```

for which you can of course also use one shared variable:

```
let val = 50, mX = val, mY = val, mXDZ = val, mYDZ = val;
```

<sub>1: You can also destructure the same property multiple times (`let {val:mX, val:mY, val:mXDZ, val:mYDZ} = {val:50};`), but it still requires an object.</sub>

Comment: sorry , i fix the issue, i need a easy way inline to assign multi variable with a value.

Comment: ya and also let mX=mY=mXDZ=mYDZ= 50; but , its ok i understand it not possible with JS, i will proceed with natural way.

Comment: I was just a little crazy about the syntax for my readability.

Comment: @jon No, that is what does not work, it would only declare `mX` and assign to global variables in the `(mY = mXDZ = mYDZ = 50)` expression. (It should even throw an exception in strict mode).

Comment: it work on my console debug ! (edit ho ok sorry yes you right)_

Comment: `let {0: mX, 0: mY, 0: mXDZ, 0: mYDZ} = [50];` and `let [mX, mY, mXDZ, mYDZ] = Array(4).fill(50);` both also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare all the variables and then in a separate statement initialize them:

```
let mX,mY,mXDZ,mYDZ;
mX = mY = mXDZ = mYDZ = 50;
```

In a variable declaration statement (`let`, `var`, or `const`), the syntax is such that each *individual* variable can have an initialization expression. There are no provisions for multiple initializations from one expression.

With destructuring, you could do this:

```
let [mX, mY, mXDZ, mYDZ] = [50, 50, 50, 50];
```

but that doesn't seem "better" in any way to me, at least for readability. It seems error-prone.

It's very important to note that

```
let mX = mY = mXDZ = mYDZ = 50;
```

is **definitely not correct**.  That statement is parsed as

```
let mX = (mY = mXDZ = mYDZ = 50);
```

That will create one local variable ("mX") and three *implicit global variables*.  In "strict" mode it would be an error; in non-strict mode it's also an error but it's harder to debug.

Comment: yes this , let [mX, mY, mXDZ, mYDZ] = [50, 50, 50, 50]; it not readable for me , i look for a more clear way, my eyes dont like this

Comment: i look for a inline assignment with single value.

Comment: @jon Right, but JavaScript syntax does not allow that. In a declaration, each variable individually can have an initialization expression. You can do a trick like Bergi's answer if you want.

Comment: ok i understand , that was my question. if is possible ? So i will native way. Thanks

Comment: ya and also let mX=mY=mXDZ=mYDZ= 50; but , its ok i understand it not possible with JS, i will proceed with natural way ,I was just a little crazy about the syntax for my readability. Also thank for you help friend