# ES6 multiple assignments/updates in one line

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Unlike other multiple assignments in one line questions, this one is different in that:

1. It's for assignments/updates
2. It's about assignments/updates to hash attributes as well.

Take a look at the following code:

```js
$ cat test.js
let a = b = "-"
console.log(a, b)
[a, b ] = ['abc', 'def']

const h = {a:"1", b:"2"}
console.log(h, h.a)
[h.a, h.b ] = ['abc', 'def']
console.log(h.a)
```

Everything works fine if running under `node` interactively:

```
> a = b = "-"
'-'
> console.log(a, b)
- -

> [a, b ] = ['abc', 'def']
[ 'abc', 'def' ]
> console.log(a, b)
abc def

> h = {a:"1", b:"2"}
{ a: '1', b: '2' }
> h
{ a: '1', b: '2' }
> [h.a, h.b ] = ['abc', 'def']
[ 'abc', 'def' ]
> h.a
'abc'
```

However, if running by `node` as script, or checking with `eslint`, there will be all kinds of problems.

Why running then under `node` interactively is OK but not if as a script?
Is it possible to fix it and make it working as script as well?

```bash
$ node -v
v16.18.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Declare and assign multi variable inLine es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708393/js-declare-and-assign-multi-variable-inline-es6)

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Use "use strict" and you'll get some errors. It is always a good habit to define *all* your variables with `let`, `const` or `var`.